# opendir return fs.Dir iterable with promises but non iterable with Sync. Why?

Tags: node.js

If I use opendir imported from fs.promises I can use fs.Dir as iterable through for ... of. If instead I use opendirSync (with the same algorithm) the script fails with the error "fs.Dir is not iterable"

promises based :

```
const {opendir} = require('fs').promises


async function run(){
    try {
    const dir = await opendir('./');
    for await (const dirent of dir)
        console.log(dirent.name);
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
}

run()
```

sync :

```
const {opendirSync} = require('fs')


function run(){
    try {
    const dir = opendirSync('./');
    for (const dirent of dir)
        console.log(dirent.name);
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    }
}

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is how you are treating the `fs.Dir` object.

`for await (const dirent of dir)` vs `for (const dirent of dir)`.

It has an [asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) so it can only be iterated with a `for await...of` loop.